# Exit code 1 http error : 1202 - wkhtmltopdf - Google Map (static image)

Tags: google-maps, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have a problem with the generation of a PDF with wkhtmlpdf. Here is my investigation:

**1- Generation of PDF with static Google Map image in default mode (default size)**

The web page and PDF contain the image.

**2- Generation of PDF with static Google Map image with business licence (customize size)**

The web page contains the image, the PDF not.

**3- In command line**

If I run in command line the wkhtmlpdf instruction, I receive this exception code:

> Exit with code 1 due to http error: 1202

The only difference between the both is the url parameters &client=XXXXX and &signature=YYY are added for the business call at Google.

I didn't find a description for this http error code on the net and I wonder me if it's really a right http error code.

I am not an expert with wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually [issue #1502](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1502) and is fixed in the development version, for which you can download a snapshot from the website.

Answer (score 1):

So, the description for this error code is: PDF generated OK, but some request(s) did not return HTTP 200.

In waiting the final version, I decided to load the Google Map image in local and after put a reference in the web page.

With this solution, I don't have any exception while the generation of PDF.

Below is the code to load and save the Google Map image.

```
String myUrl = "http://www.lesoir.be/sites/default/files/imagecache/475x317/2014/04/02/1670051557_B972392274Z.1_20140402231342_000_GIT27H8H9.2-0.jpg";

URL imageURL = new URL(myUrl);
RenderedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageURL);


File outputfile = new File("C:\\Dev\\Tmp\\Img\\image.jpg");
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputfile);
```